# Empty comment UI practice

Tags: material-design, empty

**What is the best practice to display empty commit message?**

At the moment I'm developing Google Material design desktop app where users can view commit details. When there is no commit message I'm displaying * **no message** *. Should I display **No commit comment** or maybe should I leave a blank place if there is no commit message?

Ui for example:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean comment or commit? I don't get the meaning of commit in this context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use icon. I try to show with an example. It's not perfect but when you play with color and size ıt would be a good solution [image]

Answer (score 2):

> [...] where users can view commit details.

Since displaying commit details is the main purpose of the page, and considering that commit messages are a vital part of version management, it would make sense to visually notify the user about all the details of a commit, including the lack thereof.

"No commit message entered" in clear, opaque text would be informative enough in this case and might even motivate users to enter commit messages in the future (as this is considered best practice) and indirectly improve their project quality.